# Generar registro con procedimiento almacenado MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla "series" con los campos idserie(int primary key),serie(varchar(6)),condición(enum(aceptado,aprobado,observado,rechazado)) y por ultimo certificado(varchar(6)).
Tengo que crear un procedimiento almacenado que genere registros nuevos, pero con una particularidad: a cada “idserie” creado le hará corresponder un número de 6 dígitos equivalente donde los primeros 3 dígitos de la derecha sean números del 0 al 9 y los 3 restantes caracteres ASCII de la A a la Z. (Ej: Si “idserie” fuera 12, la serie sería AAA012). Este número se cargará en el campo “serie”. El procedimiento almacenado debe admitir como parámetro la cantidad de series que se generan nuevos. Al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado se deben crear los registros de forma optimizada para que todo ocurra a la mayor velocidad posible

Lo que tengo pensado hasta ahora:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_serie(IN p_series int)
BEGIN
DECLARE last_id INT default 1;
WHILE p_series>0 DO
    last_id=MAX(series.idserie)+1;

    INSERT INTO series()
    p_series=p_series-1;
END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Poco y nada, es mi primera vez haciendo un procedimiento almacenado, y la parte de idserie me tiene trabado

Comment: @Japv agregado un poco de lo que vengo pensando

Comment: Hola @FFFF, no entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Dices: "un procedimiento almacenado que genere registros nuevos" no queda claro de donde saca la información para crear los registros nuevos. En el campo "serie" ¿las letras se generan aleatoriamente? ¿el número corresponde a "idserie", y ¿el resto de los campos con que valores los llena para cada fila nueva? Siempre ayuda ver datos de ejemplo.